# how to replace the statement_descriptor parameter with statement_descriptor_suffix as part of Stripe update

Tags: c#, nuget, stripe-payments, nuget-package

I am using stripe.net NuGet package. As a part of the latest update in stripe I need to replace the **statement_descriptor** parameter with **statement_descriptor_suffix**

[image]

**Here is the StatementDescriptor in NuGet**

[image]

currently using like this

```
var chargeOptions = new StripeChargeCreateOptions()
            {
                StatementDescriptor = statementDescriptor
            };
```

Since package is Noneditable how to achieve this, do i need to wait for update in NuGet package or is there any other way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> do i need to wait for update in NuGet package

For clarify, you're using what looks like v15.3.0 of stripe-dotnet which is quite old. The package has been updated many times since then and has supported `statement_descriptor_suffix` for some time : https://github.com/stripe/stripe-dotnet/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#27230---2019-08-08

You can either update(which is going to be a big leap and you should carefully read all the migration documents [0] and extensively test all your code).
Or you can specify paramters which the library does not know about by using ExtraParams. [1]

```
chargeOptions.addExtraParam("statement_descriptor_suffix", statementDescriptor)
```

[0] - https://github.com/stripe/stripe-dotnet/wiki

[1] - https://github.com/stripe/stripe-dotnet/blob/v15.3.0/src/Stripe.net/Services/StripeBaseOptions.cs#L7-L9